# What to use: COUNTIF or Vlookup or combined or else?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I got a big data file where I have to count how many events is per one serial number (in my case P/N) through more sheets (years). [image: Main table] Those serials are in `Column A` (grey). On second picture is lookup table, so the data from where I have to search and Count events looking at (`Column O` - yellow) and `Column A` (artikel), using terms from `Column P` for all the sheets, I mean through different year. All sheets are consistent and looking exact the same.

[image: Lookup T]

What I tried to do is: `COUNTIFS(A2:A142;VLOOKUP(A2;'Spareparts 2015'!$A$2:$O$164;15;FALSE))+COUNTIF('Spareparts 2015'!O2:O164;"Ersatz im Rahmen einer Wartung")` to look for specific term but this is not what I wanted.

Idea is to get all these specific "terms" using P/N through all years (summed), to see how many times serial number (P/N) has been used through years. And I need total number (of 5 years). As you see in main table there are more serials, and everything what is needed is some good positioned function which I cant get...

Hopefully I was clear with my issue, it is a bit hard to explain, but I eager to provide more infos!

**UPDATE!**

This is actually what I wanted to accomplish (with Pivots is possible)

[image: Sorted]

For every Serial (artikel) that I have in Calculated sheet, I wanna look and count all instances (**Grund fur ersatz** in `Column O`) through years and different sheets. Every sheet has mixed serials, and these occurrences, so I have to couple them with main table and to count total number of them, how many times something from `Column O` appeared in some of Serials through 5 years.

One option is using Pivot tables actually, but I wanted to know how I can solve it with formulas also.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the relationship between both sheets. Can you give an example of the expected result? And explain exactly how you arrive at it?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad   I did upload new pic...I might use Pivot for that but I am looking for a formula which can do the same thing. 

I need the number of how many occurrences from Column O is possible to find in 5y period in certain serial numbers (artikel). As you have 11147 with explanation (Aufbau Ersatzteillager) is 3x times in 2018 ...and there are 5 different "terms" that are possible to find, but I wrote that in the post.

Comment: Pivot seems OK for me, at least to provide the numbers to the representative. I might make one sheet with all years there and simply Pivot or in that can I can use CoUNTif function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT #2**

Given that the relationship between each serial number and the look up term is '**Many to Many**' but not 'One to One', one way to count the occurrence of each term for each serial number is to

Firstly **put all 5 years of data into one big table**, and **name** the following **ranges**:

- **Name_All** being names in `Column O` of the master data table;
- **SN_All** being serial numbers in `Column A` of the master data table.

Secondly, **create a look up sheet to list all serial numbers and associated look up terms** as shown below:

[image: Sample Look Up Table]

Then you can use **COUNTIFS** to count the occurrence for each term per serial number:

```
=COUNTIFS(SN_All,A2,Name_All,B2)
```

See following screen-shot for more clarifications.

[image: Example2]

> A better/quicker approach would be using pivot table as being mentioned by OP.

Comment: thanks but this seems to not work properly. I used =countifs and managed to get almost correct. Have to try it with =sum included because I am getting not 100% numbers.

Comment: @Mirza It seems that I've misinterpreted your question. I have updated my answer which is using **COUNTIFS** but in order for it to work you need to create a master data table and a look up sheet to list all possible combinations of serial number and look up terms given that their relationship is **Many to Many**.